# Unterschied zwischen Malen und Zeichnen

Tags: difference, meaning

Es fällt mir oft schwer wenn ich es spontan sage die beiden Worte zu differenzieren, da ich im Grunde kaum einen Unterschied sehe bzw. eher einige Gemeinsamkeiten. Denn für mich hat das eine (oft) durchaus mit dem anderen zu tun, d.h. ich würde etwas erst vorzeichnen und dann bemalen!

Aber ich denke Zeichnen ist mehr etwas was man mit dem Stift, also eher der feinere anteil. Während malen mehr mit eine Fläche zu tun hat die man mit Farbe füllt.

Wie würdet ihr die beiden Begriffe unterscheiden?

**EDIT**

Uj das ging ja schnell mit den Antworten. Noch eine weitere private Frage (ist aber eher unwichtig!): geht es euch auch so, dass man wenn man davon spricht eher selten vom Zeichnen sondern eher vom Malen spricht?

Comment: Zum Edit: Meine Frau ist DaF-, Deutsch- und Kunstlehrerin und arbeitet auch privat gern künstlerisch. Wenn ich mit ihr spreche, achte ich schon sehr auf den Kontext und bemühe mich ihr zu liebe, das korrekte Wort zu nehmen. Meine Kinder (2 & 5) malen und zeichnen auch sehr gern - ihnen gegenüber spreche ich aber durchgängig von Malen, auch wenn ich häufiger Zeichnungen als Malereien von ihnen bekomme. Für mich persönlich kommt es also darauf an, mit wem ich gerade spreche :)

Comment: Späte Edits, die neue Fragen stellen sind hier nicht gerne gesehen (bewegliche Fragen). Immerhin hat sie noch etwas mit der ursprünglichen Frage zu tun, aber besser wäre, gleich stellen oder später ein neue.

Comment: @Jan sorry die extra Frage war auch nicht als Frage -per se- gedacht. Da ich zuhause nur ca. 30- 50% Deutsch spreche würde mich einfach interessieren, ob dieses Phänomen nur bei mir auftritt! Ich werde mich hüten in Zukunft meine Frage zu re-editieren, wenn es keinen guten Grund hat (z.B. falsch formuliert/unverständlich...)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=malen&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCgQsARqFQoTCO_F062ggMgCFcsXLAodlXQHmQ&biw=1403&bih=775 https://www.google.com/search?q=zeichnen&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ7AlqFQoTCOqmg7GggMgCFUsRLAoddE0D8w&biw=1403&bih=775 https://www.google.com/search?q=malen&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ7AlqFQoTCNGK9IKggMgCFcGULAodRf0Nrw&biw=1403&bih=775&dpr=2#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=gem%C3%A4lde https://www.google.com/search?q=zeichnung&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ7AlqFQoTCPikubeggMgCFQFYLAodY80NcQ&biw=1403&bih=775

Comment: Antwort auf die Edit-Frage: Nein, mir geht es nicht so. Bei Zeichnungen spreche ich vom Zeichnen, bei Malereien vom Malen. Das kann möglicherweise aber auch damit zu tun haben, dass meine Frau in ihrer Freizeit gerne malt (mit Acrylfarben und Pinsel, Schwamm, Spachtel usw. auf Leinwand), während ich gerne mal zeichne (mit Tuschestift auf Papier). Ihre gemalten Bilder sind bunt, meine gezeichneten Bilder sind meist einfarbig (schwarz auf weiß), wobei ich aber gelegentlich auch farbige Stifte verwende, um z.B. die roten Lippen einer Frau auf einer ansonsten schwarzweißen Zeichnung hervorzuheben.

Comment: Zum Edit: Ich bin in einem kunstfernen Haushalt aufgewachsen, und ich glaube mich zu erinnern, dass für mich als Kind alles "malen" war und ich den Unterschied erst lernen musste.

Comment: Siehe auch (allerdings auf englisch): http://german.stackexchange.com/q/34373/1487

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ganz genau so wie Du es in der Frage ausgeführt hast. Als Nicht-Künstler unterscheiden sich für mich die Begriffe wie folgt:

**Zeichnen**: Mit einem Bleistift, Fineliner oder anderem feinen Stift, mit Tusche oder Tinte, aber immer mit einem Fokus auf Konturen, Umrisse, Formen. Texturen und Schattierung nur in Form von Schraffuren. Häufig einfarbig, manchmal als Vorzeichnung nur als Vorstufe für eine Malerei. Geometrie und technische Zeichnungen gehören auch dazu, das Anfertigen von Skizzen und einfachen Lageplänen. Nicht alles, was gezeichnet wird ist Kunst, nicht alle Zeichnungen wollen subjektive Eindrücke vermitteln, manchmal dienen sie "nur" der Informationsübermittlung.

**Malen**: Mit Buntstiften, Pinsel, Stempeln, Lackdosen, Pasten und Spatel. Formen, ja, aber mit Fokus auf der Fläche. Farbe, Schattierung, Textur. Häufig mehrfarbig. Malen steht für mich abseits des künstlerischen Handwerks nie in Verbindung mit nüchterner Technik und Informationsübertragung, sondern will immer *auch* eine Emotion übermitteln. Zum objektiven Bildinhalt kommt für mich immer das buchstäblich Malerische.

Comment: Das überträgt sich übrigens auch auf Dateiformate für Bilder auf Computern, wo man Vektorzeichnungen und Bitmapgrafiken (z.B. Fotos) unterscheidet.

Answer (score 4):

Du liegst mit Deiner Vermutung schon ganz richtig. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeichnung_%28Kunst%29) schreibt:

> Eine Zeichnung ist ein (Ab-)Bild, das ein Motiv (Sujet) in unterschiedlich stark vereinfachender Weise mit Linien und Strichen darstellt, was Zeichnungen von der Malerei unterscheidet, welche ein Motiv durch den flächenhaften Einsatz von Farben und Tonwerten darstellt.